# Как отследить что пользователь посмотрел ютюб видео хотя бы 75%?

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

Как такое можно сделать? На сайте есть страницы, на каждой странице есть видео youtube. Сайт на mdx Revo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решения данной задачи нужно использовать youtube API. Для вашего iframe нужно будет добавить `?enablejsapi=1`. В функции `onVideoWatched` пишите инструкции, которые нужно будет выполнить, когда пользователь просмотрит видео на указанное количество процентов

```
<iframe width="560" id="video" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<script>
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
    var player;
    var playTime=0;
    var totalTime=0;
    var intervalCheck;
    var videoWatched=false;
    var percentWatched=0.75;
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('video', {
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
    }
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
            if(!videoWatched){
                intervalCheck=setInterval(function(){
                    playTime+=0.1;
                    if((playTime/totalTime)>percentWatched){
                        onVideoWatched();
                        clearInterval(intervalCheck);
                    }
                }, 100);
            }
        }
        if(event.data !== YT.PlayerState.PLAYING){
            clearInterval(intervalCheck);
        }
    }
    function onPlayerReady(){
        totalTime=player.getDuration();
    }
    function onVideoWatched(){
        videoWatched=true;
        console.log("Просмотрено более 75% видео");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам, все предельно ясно.